# Collision script doesn't work

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have something like this: I added 2D box colliders and a 2D rigibody to a bullet and a cube. I wrote a script that should destroy the cube and the bullet when it hits the cube:

```c#
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision coll)
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
    Destroy(coll.gameObject);
}
```

But it doesn't work, I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had the same issue before

try to use `OnCollisionEnter2D` function instead